# Sony Xperia E1 D2005 Custom Recovery&CustomROM Flashing?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery, performance

I want to flash a custom ROM and install custom recovery; but when I enter ROMmanager (my device is rooted) and try to install CRW or TWRP it says "custom recovery does not support D2005 (sony xperia e1).

I want to flash a custom rom *safely* (well if I brick it I can drop it in water and say I dropped it accidentally in water; I know it's dirty trick but I don't want to be with no phone either, so let's say I have 2 lifes). My bootloader is locked, I don't know how to unlock it so I'll need help for that.

So what if my phone can flash a custom ROM, which ROM? I want the ROM to be performant and good at 3D gaming (I want to play *Despicable Me* but now with the "stock" ROM I'm getting 15 fps and 20 in clear areas).

Comment: You might wish to check: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) and our [rom-flashing tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know that exact model, but I found a pretty much complete guide to rooting, flashing and so on at XDA for your model [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/general/e1-xperia-e1-d2005-semi-official-dev-t2718947).

IMPORTANT: Remember to read the entire guide closely a couple of times before commencing the rooting and flashing procedure, so that you know exactly what you're doing and don't brick the device.

Comment: Personal critiques are not welcome here.  Also, if that post is edited or deleted, this answer becomes useless.  Please provide an overview of the process.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how there could be any personal critique in this answer. The answer was also more of an advice to the OP, as I am not familiar with that exact model, and therefore don't have any qualified experience with it. I have experience with rooting in general, and for all my rooting needs I seek to XDA, and trust them as a reliable source. Anyway to please you I will copy the procedure from the rooting post in the section of XDA that I linked to in my answer.